# Sign-out IdentityServer4 + ASP.NET Core MVC + Angular application

Tags: angular, cookies, identityserver4, logout, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a problem with proper return to client application after successful logout. First I would like to describe my setup.

- IdentityServer4 as IDP
- 2x ASP.NET Core MVC application (client from IS4 perspective). The MVC applications are using two authentication schemes ("oidc"-cookie based scheme for auth and JWT Bearer token scheme for rest api calls)
- 2x Angular 7 SPA (that is hosted by above MVC app)

Because my project has high security requirements I'm using the **Hybrid flow** for authorization. **So the login flow is as follows:**

1. User is not authenticated and visits SPA application, where he clicks on signin button
2. Angular application makes a redirect to the MVC endpoint that is under [Authorize] attribute, which initiates the OIDC challenge.
3. User is being redirected (by OidcMiddleware) to IS4 where he can type in username and password
4. User is being redirected (after successful login) back to MVC login endpoint logic (that was called in pt. 2), which is responsible for redirecting the user back to Angular SPA.
5. Angular makes a http call to a MVC endpoint that is under [Authorize] and  is responsible for returning the generate by IS4 JWT token to the client.
6. Because user is logged in into the MVC client (cookies present) the MVC backend extracts the JWT token (access_token) from the cookie and return it to the client
7. Login flow has finished at this moment (angular uses for REST API calls the JWT token) - because of that I'm using on the backend the two authentication schemes.

**So now I'm facing some issues with logout functionality. First would like to describe the flow for signout:**

1. Signed in user clicks on Signout button in angular application
2. The Spa application clears localstorage entries (where the JWT token is stored) and redirects the user to the logout action on the MVC application. Code bellow:

   [AllowAnonymous]
       public async Task Logout(string returnUrl)
       {
           await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
           await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
       }
3. The SignoutAsync on "oidc" scheme triggers the OIDC signout flow (which redirects to IS4 signout endpoint)
4. The IS4 Logout endpoint is loading the logout context (code from IS4 Quickstart)

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutDto dto)
   {
       // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
       var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(dto.LogoutId);

       if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
       {
           // delete local authentication cookie
           await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

           // raise the logout event
           await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
       }

       // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
       if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
       {
           // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
           // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
           // complete our single sign-out processing.
           string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

           // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
           return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
       }

       return View("LoggedOut", vm);
   }
   ```
5. Important is the BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync method, which loads the logout context:

   private async Task BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(string logoutId)
       {
           // get context information (client name, post logout redirect URI and iframe for federated signout)
           var context = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);

   ```
       var vm = new LoggedOutViewModel
       {
           AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = AccountOptions.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut,
           PostLogoutRedirectUri = context?.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
           ClientName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(context?.ClientName) ? context?.ClientId : context?.ClientName,
           SignOutIframeUrl = context?.SignOutIFrameUrl,
           LogoutId = logoutId
       };

       if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
       {
           var idp = User.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider)?.Value;
           if (idp != null && idp != IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider)
           {
               var providerSupportsSignout = await HttpContext.GetSchemeSupportsSignOutAsync(idp);
               if (providerSupportsSignout)
               {
                   if (vm.LogoutId == null)
                   {
                       // if there's no current logout context, we need to create one
                       // this captures necessary info from the current logged in user
                       // before we signout and redirect away to the external IdP for signout
                       vm.LogoutId = await _interaction.CreateLogoutContextAsync();
                   }

                   vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme = idp;
               }
           }
       }

       return vm;
   }
   ```
6. And here is the issue. In the case, that my mvc cookie has expired, the context has most properties set to null like for example the PostLogoutRedirectUrl. And because of that I'm not able to display the return to client link on the IS4 LoggedOut.cshtml view.

**In the case, that my mvc client cookie is not expired (valid) everything is working fine. I have the PostLogoutRedirectUrl, which allows me to return from IS4 back to the client which triggered the signout.**

Guys do you have some ideas, how could I fix that issue? A big thank you in advance!

Comment: But the IDS4 cookie should be separate from your MVC cookies, so how can it be expired?

Comment: Hello. Yes you are right IS4 cookie is separate from MVC cookie. But by default MVC cookie is valid for 20 minutes. So in the case that the user is inactive for more than 20 minutes those cookies will expire. And during signout IS4 will have no information about the client.

Comment: That’s why usually identity provider cookies don’t expire so quickly. I think you are looking for a problem in the wrong place.

Comment: Hmm I don't know to be honest. I was playing around with the quickstart examples provided by IS4 team, and they contain the issue I described (MVC client and IS4 hybrid flow). So maybe for some user that is not an issue but in my case I have the requirement, that after logout we should redirect to the client application.

Comment: Did you click remember me when logging in?

Comment: No. I'm currently not allowing that option (hiding that option).

Comment: So then its all working as expected. The persistent cookie does not get saved on the identity provider. Once the user attempts to sign out, there is nothing to sign out from because the user never had persistent sign in cookie, therefore user is already signed out.

Comment: IDS4 cookie is not expired. The MVC cookie is expired. So I'm predicting, that await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc") triggers the IDS4 signout process. And when the client (MVC) cookie is expired, then IDS4 does not get the information about the PostLogoutRedirectUrl.

Comment: Ah yeah, I understand you now. To be honest, your setup is quite peculiar already having the buffer MVC web apps to proxy the authentication to the IDP. Normally, you would have the angular apps dealing with the oidc flow themselves when it comes signing in/out.

Comment: `var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(dto.LogoutId)`: what does `vm` look like? It should contain the `PostLogoutRedirectUri` even if the user is not authenticated anymore.

Comment: Hello, when the MVC cookie is gone (deleted or expired) the vm looks like this:
AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut: false, ClientName: null, ExternalAuthenticationScheme: null, LogoutId: (this is filled with some token-like information), PostLogoutRedirectUri: null, SignOutIframeUrl: url that point to my endsession endpoint with some parameters, TriggerExternalSignout: false.

As i said in the post on top. When the MVC cookie is valid, the the properties are filled, and for example the IDS logged out view will prompt the return to client link (depending on the PostLogoutRedirectUrl)

Comment: I have tried with UserSsoLifetime but still not works, does anybody find solution?

Answer (score 0):

2. "*The Spa application clears localstorage entries (where the JWT token is stored) and redirects the user to the logout action on the MVC application.*"

^^I dnt think u should do the above step. IDS will take care of it.

Comment: No it will not. IDS does know nothing about the Spa application. From IDS perspective the MVC application is the "client".